# How to extract nested data and put them to result array JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, extract

I need extract data (array.tags.name) from all fields and put them to result array.

[image: screenshot JavaScript console]

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) What's "all fields" mean? Do you have an array of objects that look like the image of formatted text you see if you follow the link? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: fields.flatMap(f => f.tags.map(t => t.name)) then de-dupe it? Or use a set.

Comment: That tags should be options in select. So I want extract all of them and use as options in select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through with nested loop.

```
const result = [];

for (const item of array) {
  const tags = item.tags;
  for (const tag of tags) {
    result.push(tag.name);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the code to get arrays.tags.name. I have tested this with your given data as well.

```js
const data = [  {     
    tags: [   
    { name: 'LandingPage', value: 'true' },     
    { name: 'Country', value: 'GB' },     
    { name: 'Carrier', value: 'Evri' },     
    { name: 'EventCode', value: 'Dispatched' }    
    ]
  },
];
const results = [];

for (let column of data) {
  for (let tag of column.tags) {
    results.push(tag.name);
  }
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `map`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    tags: [
      { name: 'LandingPage', value: 'true' },
      { name: 'Country', value: 'GB' },
      { name: 'Carrier', value: 'Evri' },
      { name: 'EventCode', value: 'Dispatched' }
    ]
  }
];

const results = data.map(item => item.tags.map(tag => tag.name)).flat();

console.log(results);
```